# Dúvida numa equação em Pascal

Tags: pascal

Estou tendo um probleminha com um código aqui.
O que se pede é o seguinte: Dado X como parâmetro (em graus), calcular cos(x) com a soma dos 15 primeiros termos da série abaixo: [image: http://i.imgur.com/sl3DjWV.png]

Com o compilador já fui passo a passo, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar a falha. Sei que deveria realmente achar isto por conta própria, mas já estou a algum tempo nisto e me perdendo em pensamentos.

O código que fiz até então:

```
Program eq;

var
x, i, j, k, switch:integer;
coss:real;

function fatorial(n:integer):real;

var
fatN: real;

begin           
    fatN := 1;  
    for i := 1 to n do
    begin   
        fatN := fatN*i;
    end;
    fatorial := fatN; 
end; 

function expoente(x, y:integer):real;

var
range:integer;

begin
    range := y - 1;
    for k := 1 to range do
    begin
        x := x * x
    end;
    expoente := x;
end;

begin   
    readln(x);
    coss := 0;
    for j := 1 to 15 do
    begin
        if j mod 2 = 1 then
            switch := -1
        else
            switch := 1;
        coss := (coss + ((expoente(x, (j*2)))/(fatorial(j*2)))) * switch;
    end;
    coss := 1 - coss;
    writeln(coss:0:8);
end.
```

Alguém imagina aonde estou patinando?

Answer (score 1):

Essa é a série Fourier para cosseno.

Para expoente use X elevado a Y:

```
exp(y*ln(x))
```

nessa linha:

```
coss := (coss + ((expoente(x, (j*2)))/(fatorial(j*2)))) * switch;
```

Substitua por:

```
coss := coss + (exp(j*2*ln(x))/(fatorial(j*2)) * switch;
```